# Mysql Issue Escaping Quotes

Tags: php, mysql

I have been inserting some data in MYSQL with escaped quotes like this \' or \"
the issue here
is that mysql inserts the full sequence \' inestead of '

I cant find the solution online

thanks in advance

Comment: Try doing `stripslashes()` on the variable then

Comment: This is how it is supposed to work. You need to remove the slashes after you select from database using stripslashes() or str_replace().

Answer (score 0):

Rather than replace individual quotation marks, run the function

```
$cleanString = mysql_real_escape_string($incomingText);
```

(note, this method has been deprecated in place of the following method) or

```
$cleanString = mysqli_real_escape_string($incomingText);
```

This will also protect you against SQL injections. After the methods been run, insert text `$cleanString` instead of `$incomingText`.

Hope this helps.